# Why does this Java 8 lambda fail to compile?

Tags: java, lambda, compiler-errors, java-8, void

The following Java code fails to compile:

```
@FunctionalInterface
private interface BiConsumer<A, B> {
    void accept(A a, B b);
}

private static void takeBiConsumer(BiConsumer<String, String> bc) { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    takeBiConsumer((String s1, String s2) -> new String("hi")); // OK
    takeBiConsumer((String s1, String s2) -> "hi"); // Error
}
```

The compiler reports:

```
Error:(31, 58) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    java.lang.String cannot be converted to void
```

The weird thing is that the line marked "OK" compiles fine, but the line marked "Error" fails. They seem essentially identical.

Comment: is it a typo here that the functional interface method returns void?

Comment: @NathanHughes Nope. It turns out to be central to the question- see the accepted answer.

Comment: should there be code inside the `{ }` of `takeBiConsumer` ... and if so, could you give an example ... if I read this correctly, `bc` is an instance of the class/interface `BiConsumer`, and thus should contain a method called `accept` to match the interface signature ... ... and if that is right, then the `accept` method needs to be defined somewhere (eg a class that implements the interface) ... so is that what should be in the `{}`?? ... ... ... thanks

Comment: Interfaces with a single method are interchangeable with lambdas in Java 8. In this case, `(String s1, String s2) -> "hi"` is an instance of BiConsumer<String,String>.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Your lambda needs to be congruent with `BiConsumer<String, String>`. If you refer to [JLS #15.27.3 (Type of a Lambda)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3):

> A lambda expression is congruent with a function type if all of the following are true:
>
> - [...]
> - If the function type's result is void, the lambda body is either a statement expression (§14.8) or a void-compatible block.

So the lambda must either be a statement expression or a void compatible block:

- A constructor invocation is [a statement expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) so it compiles.
- A string literal isn't a statement expression and is not void compatible (cf. [the examples in 15.27.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2-230)) so it does not compile.

Comment: @BrianGordon A String literal is an expression (a constant expression to be precise) but not a statement expression.

Answer (score 44):

Basicly, `new String("hi")` is an executable piece of code that actually does something (it creates a new String and then returns it). The returned value can be ignored and `new String("hi")` can still be used in void-return lambda to create a new String.

However, `"hi"` is just a constant that doesn't do anything on it's own. The only reasonable thing to do with it in lambda body is to *return* it. But the lambda method would have to have return type `String` or `Object`, but it returns `void`, hence the `String cannot be casted to void` error.

Comment: The correct formal term is [*Expression Statement*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8), an instance creation expression may appear at both places, where an expression or where a statement is required, while a `String` literal is just an *expression* which can’t be used in a *statement* context.

Comment: The accepted answer may be formally correct, but this one is a better explanation

Comment: @edc65: that’s why this answer got upvoted as well. The reasoning for the rules and the non-formal intuitive explanation may indeed help, however, every programmer should be aware that there are formal rules behind it and in the case that the formal rule’s outcome is *not* intuitively understandable, the formal rule will still wins. E.g. `()->x++` is legal, while `()->(x++)`, basically doing exactly the same, is not…

Answer (score 23):

The first case is ok because you are invoking a "special" method (a constructor) and you are no actually taking the created object. Just to make it more clear, I'll put the optional braces in your lambdas:

```
takeBiConsumer((String s1, String s2) -> {new String("hi");}); // OK
takeBiConsumer((String s1, String s2) -> {"hi"}); // Error
```

And more clear, I'll translate that to the older notation:

```
takeBiConsumer(new BiConsumer<String, String>(String s1, String s2) {
    public void accept(String s, String s2) {
        new String("hi"); // OK
    }
});

takeBiConsumer(new BiConsumer<String, String>(String s1, String s2) {
    public void accept(String s, String s2) {
        "hi"; // Here, the compiler will attempt to add a "return"
              // keyword before the "hi", but then it will fail
              // with "compiler error ... bla bla ...
              //  java.lang.String cannot be converted to void"
    }
});
```

In the first case you are executing a constructor, but you are NOT returning the created object, in the second case you are attempting to return a String value, but your method in your interface `BiConsumer` returns void, hence the compiler error.

Answer (score 13):

The JLS specify that

> If the function type's result is void, the lambda body is either a
>   statement expression (§14.8) or a void-compatible block.

Now let's see that in detail,

Since your `takeBiConsumer` method is of void type, the lambda receiving `new String("hi")` will interpret it as a block like

```
{
    new String("hi");
}
```

which is valid in a void, hence the first case compile.

However, in the case where the lambda is `-> "hi"`, a block such as

```
{
    "hi";
}
```

is not valid syntax in java. Therefore the only thing to do with "hi" is to try and return it.

```
{
    return "hi";
}
```

which is not valid in a void and explain the error message

```
incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    java.lang.String cannot be converted to void
```

For a better understanding, note that if you change the type of `takeBiConsumer` to a String, `-> "hi"` will be valid as it will simply try to directly return the string.

---

Note that at first I tought the error was caused by the lambda being in a wrong invocation context, so I'll share this possibility with the community :

[JLS 15.27](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27)

> It is a compile-time error if a lambda expression occurs in a program
>   in someplace other than an assignment context (§5.2), an invocation
>   context (§5.3), or a casting context (§5.5).

However in our case, we are in an [*invocation context*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) which is correct.