# Return Consumer<T> with ?: operator

Tags: java, consumer

I have a problem with write simply consumer function which operator `?:`
I also don't know that it is possible to do what I want

I can't change above syntax

```
public Consumer<String> restore(){
        return (s) -> {
            if(s.equal("s")){
                "something";
            }
            else {
                "somwhere";
            }
        };
    }
```

to for example

```
public Consumer<String> restore(){
        return (s) ->  s.equal("s") ? "something" : "somwhere";
    }
```

because I get error compiller

> java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
>       target-type for conditional expression cannot be void

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262002/why-does-this-java-8-lambda-fail-to-compile

Comment: That's because `?:` is not in fact a drop-in replacement for if-else. The `?:` operator is an expression. Your consumer does not return a value, and thus has to be given a statement as its body, not an expression.

Comment: Are `"something";` and `"somwhere";` real code?

Comment: *Both* do not compile…